# AWS Lambda PhantomJS - multi language font support

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, phantomjs, font-face

I have a Lambda function to generate PDF using PhantomJS. The english version works like a charm but the issue is with other languages (Japanese, Hindi, Urdu, etc...)

I tried the solutions provided for bundling the fonts and the font config with the lambda function but no success.

Can someone suggest where am I going wrong?

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif Devanagari';
    src: url('./fonts/NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

FontConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my problem. The method to support fonts is similar to what I was doing above except for one change:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif Devanagari';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

<strike>src: url('./fonts/NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');</strike>
Removed the src: url() line as this was converting the text to raster image and the PDF size was increasing due to this.

Also, just add the required fonts in the ./fonts folder in your bundle and use the following line in your nodejs code:

```
process.env.FONTCONFIG_PATH='/var/task/fonts';
```

or better add FONTCONFIG_PATH as an environment variable in your lambda function with the value - /var/task/fonts

Closing this question as the above solution is working now.

Comment: After scouring the internet this solved my issue with phantomjs now I can use custom fonts you genius!